# Checking Facebook Request Results

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wanted to know how I can check the structure of the result when I do request to Facebook Graph API on iOS device. For instance with :

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you elaborate more about what structure you are looking to check for. Do you want to check the type of object returned? If so, maybe this are some examples - [result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] - another, [result isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the type of object (could be NSArray or NSDictionary) and then iterate accordingly

```
NSString *key, *val;
NSEnumerator myenum;      
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        for (key in result) {
            myenum = [result objectEnumerator];
            while (val = [myenum nextObject]) {
                if ([val isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                for (id entry in (NSArray *)val) {

                    if ([entry isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                        NSString * theid = [(NSDictionary *) entry objectForKey:@"id"];
                        NSString *thename = [(NSDictionary *)entry objectForKey:@"name"];
                        // do your stuff here
                    }
           }
        }
```